# проблема с open server

Tags: apache, openserver

Я начал изучать PHP и сразу возникли вопросы по становлению сервера. Я учусь по книге, но так как издание 10 года, там рассказывается про apache 2.4 которого уже нет. Тогда мне посоветовали сборник openserver, но так как учусь по книге, у меня возникли вопросы по настройке apache. Вот отрывок из книги:

> "Создадим каталог для пользователя nik. для этого добавим в C:APACHE2 папку user. в папке user создаем папку nik. внутрь папки nik добавляем файл index,html со следующим содержанием `<html><head><title>nik</title></head><body>hello</body</html>` далее с помощью блокнота открываем файл httpd-userdir.conf(который находится в папке extra) и изменяем диррективы userdir на user dir "c;/apache2/user" нахдим строку  сохраняем и закрываем файл. теперь файл httpd-userdir.conf необходимо подключить к основному конфигурационному файлу. открываем файл httpd.conf и убираем # перед строкамми; #include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf #loadmodule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so сохраняем и закрываем файл httpd.conf перезапускаем сервак. в адресной строке браузера набираем localhost/~nik/ в итоге должно отобразиться hello."

Дак в чем суть вопроса, я не могу найти httpd-userdir.conf и папку екстра, чтобы создать пользователя.

Подскажите, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `httpd.conf` ищите строку `LoadModule userdir_module...` Если он закомментирован - уберите `#`, далее перезапустите apache.

Для пользователя нужно создать каталог, например `public_html`, в его домашней дирректории. Этот каталог нужно прописать в httpd.conf

```
UserDir public_html
```

Также нужно добавить директиву

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html/">
/// настройки 
</Directory>
```

Всё должно заработать.

[Вот ссылка](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html), она поможет понять как работает модуль.

PS: Вообще, apache 2.4 жив)

Comment: Спасибо! возможно вы мне очень помогли!!! единственный нормальный ответ за неделю скитании по интернету! дай бог вам здоровья и счастья! а так же денег в карманы, денег у моря, в холодильник селедку и водку!!!